# Twilio: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, twilio, wamp

I am trying to send SMS using Twilio in PHP using the sample code included on their site as seen in the documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-php#:%7E:text=Send%20an%20SMS%20message%20in,Body%20parameters%20for%20your%20message.)

This is the full description of the error I am getting when I try run the PHP file with the Twilio code:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\wamp\www\uniSoftX\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php on line 40

Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\wamp\www\uniSoftX\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php on line 40
```

After researcch I came across an article from Twilio saying this issue can be caused by Twilio changing their root certificate to DigiCert Global Root CA. I installed that root certificate and still no luck.

I'm on windows with PHP 7.24 running WAMP server.

This is my code:

```
<?php


require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = "0000000000000000000000000";
$token = "000000000000000000000000";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$message = $twilio->messages
                  ->create("+0000000000", // to
                           [
                               "body" => "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
                               "from" => "+0000000000",
                               "mediaUrl" => ["https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg"]
                           ]
                  );

print($message->sid);
?>
```

Answer (score 10):

1. Download the following pem file: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Copy this file to c:\cert\cacert.pem
3. Open php.ini file in your favorite editor (see here for where to find it)
4. If the following configuration string: curl.cainfo exists in your php.ini, please uncomment it by removing ";" and modify the path in order to point it to the cacert.pem file you downloaded, e.g:

```
curl.cainfo=c:\cert\cacert.pem
```

5. Restart your Apache or IIS service to apply the change.

**Reference:**
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/235279367-Twilio-PHP-helper-library-SSL-certificate-problem-on-Windows

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate in C:\wamp\www\uniSoftX\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Http\CurlClient.php on line 40

CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0 , CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0
```

Comment: I'm confused. is this an answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34823444)